# Delete Cache and Cookies

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have different roles of login. Menu will be different for each user login.

I do login for *user1* and Logout and then proceeding further user.

On each login, I am using `deleteAllCookies()` before launching the url. But I am facing that the session is retained and directly logs in the last logged in user.

The following combination I have tried. it did not work for.

```
public static WebDriver driver;

1. deleteAllCookies()

2. DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
       capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_APPLICATION_CACHE, false);
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities)

3.  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();      
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);  
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities)
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: If you close and reopen the browser driver between tests, that should take care of all this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me.

```
 try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and it's working by **deleteAllCookies()**.

```
WebDriver driver = null;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/span/a[2]")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys(<Enter your email>);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(<Enter your password>);
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit-button']")).click();

Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Get");
System.out.println(driver.manage().getCookies());
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
System.out.println("Delete");
System.out.println(driver.manage().getCookies());
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```